# How to rewrite the url of a specific search?

Tags: javascript, .htaccess, redirect, search, mod-rewrite

I wish to rewrite the url of my search page result

Now is
`http://www.example.com/search/?location_name=Los+Angeles`

and i want to do like that

`http://www.example.com/search/LosAngeles`

I want to get rid of ?, the location_name and if a city has two words, i don't want to separated by +, but shown as one.

Either in .htaccess or in functions.php

**Update : My form is this**

```
<form action="<?php echo esc_url(get_the_permalink($result_page)); ?>"  method="get" >
```

this goes to

```
http://www.example.com/search/?location_name=Los+Angeles
```

what if i add to form action onsubmit="return submitAction(this);"

What js i have to put so that the url goes to location_name value e.g. Los Angeles

```
http://www.example.com/search/LosAngeles
```

Comment: "or in functions.php" - Are you using WordPress? If so, you need to change this in WordPress, not `.htaccess`. Either way, you need to change how your application (WP?) generates the URL to begin with - not something you would do in `.htaccess`. (Although you also appear to be removing the _space_ (`+`) in the "location name"?)

Comment: You can either let the request in the undesired format hit the server first, and then redirect it to the "nice" version from there; or you use JavaScript on the client side to intercept the search form submission, create the desired target URL from the entered search term, and then assign that as `location.href`. The latter saves one extra request/ round-trip to the server. And of course you will need to rewrite the nice URL into the internal format that your system understands, in either case.

Answer (score 1):

Enable `mod_rewrite` and `.htaccess` through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^results/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /search.php?search_query=$1&custom_title=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
```